# Получить из таблицы записи с помощью хранимой функции

Tags: база-данных, функции, mysql

Помогите с данным вопросом. Есть к примеру таблица users. Мне требуется с помощью хранимой функции (stored function) получить из таблицы записи по определённому запросу.

Например, у меня в таблице поля:

```
user_id int, full_name varchar(64), email varchar(64)
```

Вот пример, чего хотелось бы:

```
select * from get_user(1)
```

где 1 - `user_id`.

Comment: ну и что? почитай как оформляются stored function и напиши... там все просто

Comment: по поводу хранимых процедур - я знаю. Проблема в том, что есть необходимость использовать именно в php 4, на 5ом - с
Если в 4ом запрашивать с помощью хранимых процедур - будет возвращена ошибка, потому как необходимо использовать расширение mysqli (а оно доступно лишь в 5ой ветке, или я не прав)

Comment: @akm74, версия PHP-интерпретатора не имеет значения. Имеет значение версия MySQL-сервера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В MySQL ни хранимые процедуры ни функции не возвращают табличный результат.

Функция, по определению, через `RETURN` возвращает скалярное значение. А у процедуры есть типы параметров `OUT` и INOUT. Но, все равно, это несколько входных/выходных параметров, а не таблица.

Есть правда один вариант. В теле процедуры можно создать открытый запрос типа `SELECT * FROM table`, и при выполнении такая процедура вернет таблицу. Но толку от такой реализации - ноль. Потому как такой результат ни во что не обернешь и ни чем не отфильтруешь.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE proc()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM table;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
CALL proc();
```